# Is it possible to make Firefox open a URL in a popup window?

Tags: shell-script, firefox, javascript

I would like Firefox (the new super fast Quantum with low memory usage) to open some URLs in a special/popup window, i.e. almost without anything (toolbar, menu bar, tab bar, address bar, etc.) other than the web content.

At the moment I can only do something like this by clicking a link in an HTML file with the following code:

```
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/"
   target="popup"
   onclick="window.open('https://web.whatsapp.com/','popup', 'width=650,height=900');">
   WhatsApp
</a>
```

I wish I could do this by simply entering a command from terminal - or a standalone shell script would also do (ideally without the address bar, and positioned to the right and not left ;-)

Any suggestions or ideas please?

Comment: Have you checked the man page for firefox?  I would be pretty surprised if there isn't an option to do this (I know for Chrome it's `--app`, but I bet Firefox is different).

Comment: In the absence of such an option I've created a Q&A concerning this matter here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410043/how-to-launch-a-special-whatsapp-web-window-in-firefox/410044

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a local on-disk helper file:

popopen.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
u = window.location.href
popupwin = window.open(u.substring(u.indexOf("#")+1), "popup", "menubar=no, location=yes");
popupwin.opener.close();
</script></head><body></body></html>
```

With that file, you can simply run via the commandline,

```
Firefox -url file:popopen.html#https://web.whatsapp.com/
```

It's supplied your URL as an Anchor Link: `#https://web.whatsapp.com/`.

Then it closes the Popup's Parent (itself).

This works as of Firefox 84 (the latest FF version with Flash)
but may not work on future versions
as Mozilla continues to remove functionally. 
It also works for all users/profiles.

This local-disk file is a workaround, as you previously
could just run `javascript:code` as a URL,
but now that requires a bookmark-hack that is user-specific. 
Also, directly closing the original window was removed;
hence the closing of the popup's parent.

I needed the 'popup's read-only URL Bar
so that Flash can be allowed on the page.  And this achieves that.

### If you don't a *popup*'s read-only URL Bar, there are much simpler ways

```
Firefox --kiosk https://web.whatsapp.com/
```

will open the link full screen with no menu or window bar,
but it's hard to close since there's no "X".

### Better yet is "[Single Site Browser](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1292666)" mode

```
Firefox -ssb https://web.whatsapp.com/
```

It's the exact same as a popup but without the URL bar, and it's easy. 
The only problem is that it must be enabled first in about:config
(see [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1292666)).

This is an old question,
and I'm responding with a working answer for an old browser. 
But I needed this for Flash on Debian 9,
and found this question, which didn't have an answer. 
So I hope this can/will help others using old FF 84
for true flash3 compatibility (VMware). 
But really, if you don't need the read-only URL bar shown,
`-ssb` is the better answer.